# How do I navigate complex view hierarchy based on remote notification in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification

My app has several view controllers and if I receive a push notification from Apple, what is the proper way to display the appropriate view controller so that I present the most relevant view (based on said notification) in my view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You could map a URL to different View Controllers.

That way if you receive a URL like app://friends/12345/games you would know you have to go to:

1. the friends section
2. friend id:12345
3. friend id:12345's games

Comment: [This may be a useful link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) for others trying to do the same thing. I didn't find an example of this type from Apple but perhaps I missed it. One thing I think should be brought to light is if a user changes the view hierarchy in a new version release, they should make sure that these URLs may be backward compatible, i.e., Notifications may change independently of the UI.